# documentation of Qt 4.8.2 in VS2010

Tags: qt

Highlights of Visual Studio Add-In 1.1.11 include:

Documentation support for Visual Studio 2010, and documentation updated
Fixed always moc’ing problem. (QTVSADDINBUG-92)
Fixed .pro file opening having include to “.” path. (QTVSADDINBUG-117)

how to use the integrated documentation？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [visual studio plugin](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in) does docs integration as well as everythign else needed to make Qt work perfectly with Qt